# Good C++ book for an Intermediate programmer to become an expert programmer?

Tags: c++

Hello I have intermediate knowledge of C++ and I want to brush up my skills for game programming, so can anyone recommend any good c++ book.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The C++ Programming Language** Written by Bjarne Stroustrup (the inventor of C++)